# Nearest neighbor graph corresponding to 3d sphere packing

Tags: graphs-and-networks, geometry, packing, igraphm

I had used

```
mesh = IGLatticeMesh["Hexagonal", Polygon@CirclePoints[3, 6], MeshCellLabel -> {2 -> "Index"}]

graph = IGMeshCellAdjacencyGraph[mesh, 2, VertexCoordinates -> Automatic];
```

from a thread here to create nearest neighbor graph in Mathematica for a Hexagonal Grid. I would like to do the same in 3D with  alternative sphere packing strategies.  I have not figured out how to extend the item above

Comment: If you can generate the points you need in 3D, then `IGGabrielGraph` will give you what you need in most cases. You did not mention any specific point arrangements you want, so I won't go into that.

Comment: Thank you.  That is helpful.  Your IG package is most useful.  The point arrangement is Hexagonal Close Packing (HCG)

Answer (score 1):

A few approaches:

```
NearestNeighborGraph[RandomReal[1, {50, 3}], 2]
```

[image]

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {6, 17, 3}];
MeshConnectivityGraph[VoronoiMesh[#], 0] & /@ data
```

[image]

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {6, 17, 3}];
MeshConnectivityGraph[DelaunayMesh[#], 0] & /@ data
```

[image]